# Como converter os dados em tabela no Power BI após integrar uma API com os dados em JSON?

Tags: json, api, powerbi, powerquery

Olá, gostaria de um apoio na conversão dos dados obtidos de uma API em JSON para uma tabela no power query do Power BI.

[Na imagem o resultado da consulta da API tenho um retorno do tipo lista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBWVo.png)

Ao converter para uma tabela percebo que a coluna 1 traz os ID's porém as 3 próximas colunas possui uma "lista de dados" em cada linha.

[Após expandir a lista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqmcN.png)

Ao expandir a nova coluna vejo que o número de ID se repete várias vezes e isso está OK até aqui

[Expandindo a coluna Power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfVVh.png)

O problema é quando vou expandir a próxima colunas, os dados não são referenciados por linha. Os dados de wind_speed e power estão se repetindo, porém em datas diferentes.

[Expandindo todas as colunas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIRmR.png)

Para cada ID temos um conjunto de dados de DATA, WIND_SPEED e POWER diferentes. No JSON consigo visualizar que dentro de cada ID os dados estão separados corretamente. Minha dúvida tem sido nessa conversão dos dados no Power Query do Power BI.

**Segue o código completo da consulta no Power Query:**

```
let
// Definir os dados JSON
json = [
    api_token = "cb8551da59dbdf91be8371df4a03dddb",
    power_source = "wind",
    id = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40},
    variables = {"wind_speed", "power"},
    end_date = "20240601",
    integration = "daily"
],

// Converter o JSON em uma string JSON formatada
jsonString = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(json)),

// Definir a URL
url = "https://api.tempook.com/geracao/v1/forecast/multiforecast/range/integration",

// Obter os dados da API usando o método POST
response = Web.Contents(
    url,
    [
        Headers = [
            #"Content-Type"="application/json"
        ],
        Content = Text.ToBinary(jsonString),
        ManualStatusHandling={405}
    ]
),

// Converter a resposta JSON em uma tabela
jsonResponse = Json.Document(response),
#"Convertido para Tabela" = Record.ToTable(jsonResponse),
Value = #"Convertido para Tabela"{0}[Value],
#"Convertido para Tabela1" = Table.FromList(Value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Column1 Expandido" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Convertido para Tabela1", "Column1", {"id", "power", "wind_speed", "times"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.power", "Column1.wind_speed", "Column1.times"}),
#"Column1.power Expandido" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Column1 Expandido", "Column1.power"),
#"Column1.wind_speed Expandido" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Column1.power Expandido", "Column1.wind_speed"),
#"Column1.times Expandido" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Column1.wind_speed Expandido", "Column1.times")
```

in
#"Column1.times Expandido"